# RaphaelJS / CSS - Animating text/numbers

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, raphael

So, I am just diving into simple web animations for a game, and I am looking for advice. Eventually, I'll get a good grip on beziers and arcs and learn how to animate along a path to get some nice Diablo III-esque curving numbers but, for now, I am just trying to get the fundamentals down.

[First (real) attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/rLcwax9k/4/)

The key code is pretty simple-

```
paper.text(170, 95, dmgValue).attr({fill:"white", "font-size":16}).animate({
    transform:"t0,-50", "fill-opacity":0} ,500).node.setAttribute("class", "no-select");
```

A CSS styling prevents the text from being highlighted (thanks to a user here for the help). The main issue, is that the text is still there with no opacity- you can hover over it and see the text cursor. Although it works, it' kind of messy looking. Also, since there is no variable assigned, I don't think I can dispose of it with Element.remove();

[Where I am at now](http://jsfiddle.net/rLcwax9k/7/)

There were a lot of small revisions I made in-between saved versions that made the code to the bulkiness that it is now. I wanted the ability to limit the number of numbers flying around at once (for slower computers), so I put them into an array that can be looped endlessly and used, although that probably isn't needed and it wouldn't be a big deal to leave it out.

Also moved from using transform, to setting the y-coords, and placing the .hide() into a separate function for the callback (which, for some reason worked instead of placing it at the end of the animation).

This version appears to work at first, but the animations get interrupted when you click too many times and I'm not sure why. I am sure I can figure it out in the end with enough time, but I might be making this too complicated, anyway. The full code-

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 350, 350);
paper.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "Black";

var dmgValues = [],
    dmgValuesIndex = 0,
    maxMsgs = 15,
    dmgXMaxOffset = 25,
    dmgYMaxOffset = 25,
    dmgXRef = 170 - dmgXMaxOffset,
    dmgYRef = 250 - dmgYMaxOffset,
    dmgMaxDistance = 50;

for (i=0; i< maxMsgs; i++) {
    dmgValues[i] = paper.text().attr({fill:"white", "font-size":16});
    dmgValues[i].node.setAttribute("class", "no-select");
    dmgValues[i].hide();
}

var toggle = paper.rect(150, 270, 50, 25).attr({fill:"green"});

toggle.click(function() { doHit(); });

function doHit() {
    var dmgHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1,
        xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * dmgXMaxOffset) + 1,
        yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * dmgYMaxOffset) + 1;
    dmgValues[dmgValuesIndex].show();
    if (dmgValues[dmgValuesIndex].status() == 1) { dmgValues[dmgValuesIndex].stop(); }
    dmgValues[dmgValuesIndex].attr({x:dmgXRef + xPos, y:dmgYRef + yPos, text:dmgHit,
      "fill-opacity":1}).animate({y:dmgYRef - dmgMaxDistance, "fill-opacity":0}, 600,
      "linear", function() { afterEffects(dmgValues[dmgValuesIndex]) });
}

function afterEffects (afterTarget) {
    afterTarget.hide();
    dmgValuesIndex++;
    if (dmgValuesIndex >= maxMsgs) { dmgValuesIndex = 0; }
}
```

CSS:

```
.no-select {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see the problem with the first example. I can't hover or see a text cursor there ?

Comment: Hello again :) I've altered the first one a tiny bit by removing the fill-opacity animation: http://jsfiddle.net/rLcwax9k/8/  Is it possible to reference them, even though they don't have a variable name?

Comment: Depends what you mean. You could return the object you create as part of the function and assign it to a value. Not quite sure what the problem is still. I'd be tempted to write a new question with a more concise example (like in the latter jsfiddle) with the problem being experienced and how to replicate it.

Comment: Did the 8th version of the example not show the same behavior on your browser? I only tested on Chrome and IE (been meaning to install FF). I took off the opacity fade in the animation to show that the text was still there. Even though the alpha changed, the object was still physically there, and the cursor changed when hovering. It just looked sloppy, and I couldn't call the .hide() method on an object I did not directly define (at least I don't think). But, I think I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out!

http://jsfiddle.net/rLcwax9k/10/

One thing I noticed was that that the incrementer was in the callback function that occurred after the animation, so it wasn't really counting right. But, mainly, because the `dmgValuesIndex` was global, and was getting incremented on each click. So, by the time the animation was done, it was doing functions based on whatever the current count was at the end of the animation in the callback, which may not have been the right one. So, I just put a parameter on the function and used that as the reference throughout the call and passed it to the callback.

Heh, I am sort of beginning to see why a lot of languages need setter and getter methods on their objects. This should be a good lesson to noobs like me on operating with global variable scope and their possible side-effects.

However, before I accept an answer, I am still looking for any other methods that may be more efficient.

Main code-

```
function doHit(iter) {
    this.iter = iter;
    var dmgHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1,
        xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * dmgXMaxOffset) + 1,
        yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * dmgYMaxOffset) + 1;
    dmgValues[iter].show();
    if (dmgValues[iter].status() == 1) { dmgValues[iter].stop(); }
    dmgValues[iter].attr({
        x:dmgXRef + xPos,
        y:dmgYRef + yPos,
        text:dmgHit,
        "fill-opacity":1
    })
    .animate({
        y:(dmgYRef + yPos) - dmgMaxDistance,
        "fill-opacity":0},
        1000,
        ">",
        function() {
            dmgValues[iter].hide();
        }
    );
}
```